# Is a QEMU installation on a raw disk backward compatible?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, disk-image

I create a qemu image like this:

```
qemu-img create -f raw my_disk.raw 2G
```

and (manually) install debian into it:

```
qemu-system-i386 my_disk.raw -enable-kvm -m 1024 -cdrom my_debian_cd.iso
```

Say I do these steps with qemu version `2.0.0`, can I start the disk with an older version of qemu, e.g. version `1.0.50`? If yes, do I have to convert the disk somehow? Is it save to use an image created with a newer version or do I have to expect problems?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being RAW, the file contain a plain bit-level representation of the data inside it. In other words, RAW disks are always "compatible", because they contain no special structure/headers.

What really matter, even with RAW disks, it the virtual hardware supported: a more recent QEMU version can present to the guest, by default, some virtualized hardware that older QEMU versions do not support.

Anyway, the virtualized hardware is often the same between the various QEMU version, so try it and report back your (lack of) success!

Comment: To sum it up: You are rather positive that a raw image is backward compatible but you are not sure due to possible problems with  "virtual hardware". What do you mean by "virtual hardware"?

Comment: Is the virtual platform which is presented to the guest by the host. In other words, it is the "virtual PC" on which the guest runs.